# Group row data of a 2d array by one column and sum another column within each group

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, grouping

I need to sum the column data of rows after grouping by another column.

Example input:

```
[
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'John00', 'value' => 0.4],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Ann01', 'value' => 0.001],
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'John00', 'value' => 0.2],
    ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Ann', 'value' => 0.1],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Ann01', 'value' => 0.01],
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'John00', 'value' => 0.3],
]
```

How can I consolidate rows with the same `id` and sum the `value` values in each group to return an indexed array of associative arrays?

Desired result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => John00
            [value] => 0.9
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Ann01
            [value] => 0.011
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Ann
            [value] => 0.1
        )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you are trying to do - I assume you want the sum grouped by the id for each distinct id to populate a flat associative array, but I may be wrong.

```
$sums = array();

foreach ($source as $ar) {
    //create an entry for this id in the array of sums if does not exist.
    if (!isset($sums[ $ar['id'] ])) {
        $sums[ $ar['id'] ] = 0;
    }
    
    //add 'value' key to sum for that id
    $sums[ $ar['id'] ] += $ar['value'];
}

//sort by id
ksort($sums);

print_r($sums);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 0.9
    [2] => 0.011
    [3] => 0.1
)
```

Comment: you assumed right, but i get only the sum of the last id. I think i do a mistake somewhere. many thx

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's coming from a database, and the query is the best place to do such things. (if this is not data from a db, just ignore this answer).

```
SELECT id, MAX(name), SUM(value)
FROM YourTable
-- add your WHERE-constraints here
GROUP BY id;
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that the result array has the same structure of the input array (an indexed array of associative rows) -- just reducing the total row count in the process -- push the whole as a reference variable into the result array whenever a unique `id` value is encountered.  If a row is encountered where the `id` has been encountered before, only add the current `value` value to the `value` value in the reference.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/cILOR))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    if (!isset($ref[$row['id']])) {
        $ref[$row['id']] = $row;
        $result[] =& $ref[$row['id']];
        continue;
    }
    $ref[$row['id']]['value'] += $row['value'];
}
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Pseduo-code:

```
$totals = array();

function add($in)
{
   global $totals;
   if(!isset($totals($in['id']))
   {
      $totals[$in['id']] = $in['value'];
   }else
   {
      $totals[$in['id']] += $in['value'];
   }
}

array_walk('add',$input_array);

var_dump($totals);
```

Comment: This pseudo-code has too many flaws to be helpful to researchers.